# Systemd throws incomprehensible permission denied

Tags: systemd, centos8

This should be an easy one, but I'm completely lost. I have a script in my /etc/systemd/system directory to start an IBM HTTP Server:
ihs.service

```
[Unit]
Description=IBM HTTP Server
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/appl/ihs/logs/httpd.pid
ExecStart=/appl/ihs/bin/apachectl start
ExecStop=/appl/ihs/bin/apachectl graceful-stop
ExecReload=/appl/ihs/bin/apachectl graceful
PrivateTmp=true
LimitNOFILE=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  355 Jun 21 13:06  ihs.service

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 wasusr wasgrp 3414 May 12 14:02 /appl/ihs/bin/apachectl

systemctl start ihs.service gives an error and this in the journal:

> ### Jun 21 12:34:21 (myhostname) systemd[2814762]: ihs.service: Executing: /appl/ihs/bin/apachectl start
> Jun 21 12:34:21 (myhostname) systemd[2814762]: ihs.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
> Jun 21 12:34:21 (myhostname) systemd[2814762]: ihs.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /appl/ihs/bin/apachectl: Permission denied
> -- Subject: Process /appl/ihs/bin/apachectl could not be executed
> -- Defined-By: systemd
> -- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
>
> ### -- The process /appl/ihs/bin/apachectl could not be executed and failed.
>
> -- The error number returned by this process is 13.

How is it possible that systemd reports that this process could not be executed when it has the rights it needs?
Running the same command from the command line works flawlessly. Also the pid file directory exists

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was a simple problem: SELinux.
Normally I switch this to permissive or switch it off on machines where I need to install COTS software, but I had forgotten this one.
So, in /etc/selinux/conf set SELINUX= to either permissive or disabled